# iMac has no internet in Safari but the same time has in Firefox

Tags: macos, internet, safari, updates

I have a 21" Apple iMac with Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari installed.

The past two days, I can't access the internet in Safari at all, but still can in Firefox or Chrome.  I also can't update Safari as well...

What can I do to fix this?  What's wrong?

Comment: What error message (if any) is displayed? And why can't you update Safari?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can load http://74.125.224.81/ from Safari. That's an IP address for www.google.com. If it works, but www.google.com doesn't work, then you have a DNS problem that's only affecting Safari.

Try doing:

```
sudo killall -9 mDNSResponder
```

This will cause one of Mac OS X's DNS resolver systems to be restarted, and could clear up the problem. There is more than one DNS resolver in Mac OS X, and Firefox and Chrome may not be using mDNSResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in a similar situation where I didn't have access via Safari on iMac, but Firefox and IE on the PC did.

I used the "Reset Safari" command from the Safari menu next to the Apple menu and the internet access seems to be back through Safari.